# TypeErrror: monthSelectPlugin is not a constructor when attempting to use Flatpickr plugin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, npm, flatpickr, stimulusjs

I am attempting to use the monthSelectPlugin for flatpickr within a rails app. I have it pinned in my importmap like so:

```
pin "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr@4.6.13/dist/plugins/monthSelect/index.js"
```

And am using it in a stimulus controller like so, using the the example from their documentation:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import flatpickr from "flatpickr"
import * as monthSelectPlugin from 'flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect';
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['picker']
  connect() {
    const picker_div = this.pickerTargets;
    
    flatpickr(picker_div, {
      plugins: [
        new monthSelectPlugin({
          shorthand: true, //defaults to false
          dateFormat: "m.y", //defaults to "F Y"
          altFormat: "F Y", //defaults to "F Y"
          theme: "dark" // defaults to "light"
        })
    ]});
  }
}
```

But attempting this results in an error:

```
TypeError: monthSelectPlugin is not a constructor
```

It took long enough to actually get this properly imported, does anyone understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

import `monthSelect` instead:

```
import monthSelect from 'flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect';
```

Answer (score 1):

importmap change to

```
pin "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:flatpickr@4.6.13/dist/plugins/monthSelect/index.js"
```

import

```
import monthSelectPlugin from "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect"
```